# Check constraint on new table using an IN condition is not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a new table that included a check constraint using an in clause to create a list of allowed entries, or at least that was the plan.  The create table command executed without error however in testing I am able to insert rows without the constraint preventing incorrect values for the column "CAUSE"

I have done a bit of internet reasearch but I have not figured this one our yet.  I will include the create table statement bellow.

'''

```
USE TEST 
GO

CREATE TABLE EMP_POINTS (
ROWID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
WEEK_ID nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
EMPLOYEE_ID nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
DATE date NOT NULL,
CAUSE nvarchar(15),
POINTS decimal(2,1),

PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID, DATE),
CONSTRAINT FK_EmpID FOREIGN KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ID),
CONSTRAINT chk_cause CHECK (
                            CAUSE IN('Late In','Early Out','E & L', 'NCNS', 'Absent', '0.5','1.0', NULL)
                           )
);
```

'''

I would expect that the only values which would be allowed in the CAUSE column would be the ones identified in the chk_cause constraint however it is allowing any values to be entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHECK` constraints are different from `WHERE` and `CASE` conditions.  A `CHECK` constraint only fails when the result is *explicitly* false.  The others require that the condition is *explicitly* true.  The difference is how `NULL` values are handled.

So, you can write your constraint as:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_cause CHECK (CAUSE IN('Late In', 'Early Out', 'E & L', 'NCNS', 'Absent', '0.5', '1.0')
                           )
```

Then, only these values *and* `NULL` will be allowed (assuming `CAUSE` is not declared `NOT NULL`).

The problem with your version is that other values will result in `NULL` (due to the `NULL` in the `IN` list).  And that passes the `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: Im not going to argue with results and that deffiantly worked, but could you provide a little more detail to the explonation.  I would think that an entry like 'wehrweh' would be evaluated as explicitly flase in both statements.  I dont fully understand how removing the NULL value from the check would alter the True / False evaluation for an entry that was not null and not in the list?  Thank you again for your origional answer, it is clearly correct.

Comment: @Dru . . . Nope.  An alternative value will be compared to `NULL`, so the result will be `NULL`, not "false".

Comment: Ok, so the comparison basically uses multiply by 0 logic for NULL, anything compared to NULL is NULL,  Interesting.  I learn something new every day.  Thanks Gordon

Comment: @Dru . . . Yes.  In SQL, `NULL` (generally) has the semantics of "unknown value" rather than "missing value".  Hence, almost any comparison to `NULL` returns "unknown value" (`NULL`) rather than true or false.